# Update field value from DB without using req.body in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to update a value from X post found in my database, the thing is that it will be updated by triggering a button not a form in my front end app.

I know that you need to use `req.body` when sending data from a form but what do I have to do when I'mm not sending any?

```
// Fetch post
const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
// Get post field and declare newValue according to currentValue
post.hidden === 'yes' ? post.hidden === 'no' : post.hidden === 'yes';

post = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, post.hidden, {
  new: true,
  runValidators: true
});

res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: post });
```

This is more of a boolean field using a string. I just need it to change from `yes` to `no`(and viceversa) everytime I send a request to the API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it!. If anyone having the same troubles as me, the way to update it is by using a different method of updating instead of the findByIdAndUpdate. Here it is the answer:

```
post.hidden === 'yes' ? (post.hidden = 'no') : (post.hidden = 'yes');
await post.save();
res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: post });
```